# Unable to access bbc.co.uk - "Error resolving hostname www.bbc.co.uk: timed out" - possibly proxy related

Tags: dns, proxy, ip-address

I'm having some problems accessing bbc.co.uk.  Each time I try I receive the error message:

```
**Connection Error**
Unable to connect to the requested site.

**Details**
Error resolving hostname www.bbc.co.uk: timed out
```

It's up according to `downorjustme.com`.

This may be very much my fault, given that I recently messed around (foolishly) with some ways of getting BBC Iplayer to work from abroad (I'm still abroad, in Spain).  Now the lagado proxy test says:

```
**Proxy Test**
This request appears to have come via a proxy.
The proxy host is 108.Red-80-58-205.staticIP.rima-tde.net which has ip address 80.58.205.108
The proxy informs us that the client host ip address was 88.21.255.217"
```

I'd really appreciate it if anyone had any suggestions on how to get my IP address back to how it should be, so I can access websites normally!  Thanks.

EDIT:  Various other members living in Spain using with Telefonica as their ISP seem to be experiencing the same problem, so this might not actually be my fault/resolvable by me...

Comment: Do you use Telefonica's DHCP server? If so - did you tried setting your own preferred DNS servers such as OpenDNS or DynDNS, ... instead of those that was supplied to you via DHCP?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you cannot resolv bbc.co.uk to 212.58.224.138

Maybe something is blocking your DNS request or denying reply for specific addresses.

Did you try : `nslookup bbc.co.uk` in a command prompt?
Try also to access the IP I gave in this post, to see if it connects.

Comment: Result for nslookup bbc.co.uk

Server: UnKnown
Address: 192.168.1.1

Non-authoritative answer:
Name: bbc.co.uk
Address: 212.58.224.138


Trying to access the IP you gave in this post gives:

"- Public Service Message

Sorry, the address you are looking for is not available.

You will find almost all BBC public service content on http://www.bbc.co.uk/ and by following links to the content you require."

Which at least looks like some form of connection...

Comment: Well apparently bbc.co.uk and www.bbc.co.uk are different. Does a `nslookup www.bbc.co.uk` gives you 212.58.224.70 ?

Comment: Nope: 212.58.246.94

Comment: Ok, at least the reverse lookup show `bbc-vip015.cwwtf.bbc.co.uk` as address. Does the IP works in the browser? All of this is a little weird I must say.

Comment: The IP I have (212.58.246.94) takes me to www.bbc.co.uk but I get the same error message as always.